# Why is MySQL hanging on this simple subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery, query-optimization

I have this simple query which runs in a about 5 seconds and return about 500 records, but then why I try to use it in a compound statement MySQL just hangs

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST_ID FROM WORK
    GROUP BY ARTIST_ID
    HAVING AVG(WORK_MILLIS_VIEWED) > 10
```

The query below however never terminates.  According to the process list it's just creating a temporary table, even though it should run only slightly longer than the sub-query, because the artist table is trivially small.

```
SELECT ARTIST_NAME FROM ARTIST
    WHERE ARTIST_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST_ID
         FROM WORK GROUP BY ARTIST_ID
         HAVING AVG(WORK_MILLIS_VIEWED) > 10)
```

Am I making a stupid mistake?  The database doesn't seem to be doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a hard time with subqueries in the WHERE clause. It usually decides to run the subquery many times (once for each distinct ARTIST_ID value you compare to the subquery) even though you know and I know that the subquery won't change.

A workaround for this is to run the subquery in the FROM clause and JOIN to it:

```
SELECT A.ARTIST_NAME 
FROM (
    SELECT ARTIST_ID FROM WORK 
    GROUP BY ARTIST_ID HAVING AVG(WORK_MILLIS_VIEWED) > 10
) AS T
JOIN ARTIST A ON A.ARTIST_ID = T.ARTIST_ID
```

This will at least run the subquery just once, and store it in a temporary table while it joins to the other table instance.

You will also benefit from an index on the pair of columns `(ARTIST_ID, WORK_MILLIS_VIEWED)` in that order.

Comment: Ah I see, so MySQL is repeating the aggregate query, and it'll take about 500x5seconds- but I can change the isolation level and it sohuld go away.

Comment: @awiebe - Let us know if the isolation_level has that effect.

Comment: @Rick James - Well looking at it, it seems I could alter the isolation level, since my database isn't live, this works for my application, but would be not good for other.  It seems in this case the best thing to do is acquire a lock on the subquery table.

Comment: Ok so in the end, I used table locks, pulled the statistics into my business logic, and then put them back in artist with updates.  This operation doesn't play nice with a transactional storage engine, so the best you can do is suspend transactions for a moment quickly run a batch job, update and then unlock.